# H145 helicopter type rating trainings

Tags: helicopter, easa-regulations, type-ratings

There are different variants of H145 helicopter (BK117), there are BK117, BK117 C2, BK117 D2 and BK117 D3 helicopter. So if you finish type rating training for example for BK117 D2, and you want to fly D3 variant, do you need any kind of flight training (differences training), or only theoretical (familiarization training) is enough, and where can I find more informations about this.